# Huge amount of RU to write document of 400kb - 600kb on Azure cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

This is the log of my azure cosmos db for last write operations:

[image]

Is it possible that write operations of documents with size between 400kb to 600kb have this costs?

Here my document (a list of coordinate):

[image]

Basically I thought at the beginning it was a hotPartition problem, but afterwards I understood (I hope) that it is a problem in the loading of documents ranging in size from 400kb to 600kb. I wanted to understand if there was something wrong in the database setting, in the indexing policy or other as it seems to me anomalous that about 3000 ru are used to load a json of 400kb, when in the documentation it is indicated that to load a file of equal size at 100kb it takes about 50ru. Basically the document to be loaded is a road route and therefore I would not know in what other way to model it.

This is my indexing policy:

[image]

Thanks to everybody. I spent months behind this problem without having solutions...

Comment: try changing incluidedPaths only to needed paths or just set indexing mode to lazy and test your insert

Comment: @4c74356b41 If i use the lazy mode what i risk? For example.. if i have an azure cosmos db trigger that for every type of specific document execute a query with ST_DISTANCE respect another document, this may not trigger or trigger but the result of the query may be inconsistent?

Because i try with lazy idexing and the ru get down by 2 orders of magnitude. Best practise what is it?

Comment: yeah, queries results might not be accurate. you just need to configure indexing properly. you are just indexing too much. also, you might want to loosen consitency

Comment: Do not use Lazy Indexing. Lazy indexing provides no way of measuring index progress and can result in queries with missing data and/or expensive queries as the result of scans.

Comment: Just like others are saying, you indexing strategy needs looking at. You have fairly large documents if they are 400kb-600kb. Set your strategy to index only fields that you are querying later. Additionally, as one other person said, reduce your document. You probably are storing everything in one document and sometimes that isn't a good strategy. Look where you can separate. If you have fields/sub sections of those docs that are not used or rarely used by your application(s), then store those in a document and have a way to link to that doc from your main doc that is often used.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure what the expected RU/s cost should be to ingest a 400KB-600KB item. The cost of this operation will depend on the size of the item, your indexing policy and the structure of the item itself. Greater hierarchy depth is more expensive to index.

You can get a good estimate for what the cost for a single write for an item will be using the [Cosmos Capacity Calculator](https://cosmos.azure.com/capacitycalculator/). In the calculator, click Sign-In, cut/paste your index policy, upload a sample document, reduce the writes per second to 1, then click calculate. This should give you the cost to insert a single item.

One thing to note here, is if you have frequent updates to a small number of properties I would recommend you split the documents into two. One with static properties, and another that is frequently updated. This can drastically reduce the cost for updates on large documents.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pull the RU cost for a write using the SDK.

> Check storage consumed
> To check the storage consumption of an Azure Cosmos container, you can run a HEAD or GET request on the container, and inspect the x-ms-request-quota and the x-ms-request-usage headers. Alternatively, when working with the .NET SDK, you can use the DocumentSizeQuota, and DocumentSizeUsage properties to get the storage consumed.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/optimize-cost-storage#check-storage-consumed).